# GridLayout Column width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

I have 2 columns in my `GridLayout`. What I want to do is make those columns take up half of the width of the screen each and then have its child contents fill their own cells width/height. I tried setting the children to `fill_parent` but that just causes the first one to take over the entire layout. And it seems GridLayout doesn't support `weight`? Maybe there is a better layout to use, but I want a Grid style layout so that seems like the natural choice.

Comment: Are you trying to fill a specific height/width? And do you want all grid items to be the same height?

Comment: yes. I have 2 columns. I want their widths to be 50% of the screen width, so together they will equal the width of the screen. and then their height to be the same as the width in pixels. So they will be square.

Comment: did you found any solution? if yes then please share. I also want same kind of functionality.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This code is available on pre API21 with support library!

I have a simple piece of code to show 4 buttons in a gridLayout of 2 columns that take 50% of the available space: 
perhaps it can help

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="2"
    >


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />

       <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        />



</GridLayout>
```

Solution is perhaps this :

```
android:layout_gravity="fill"
android:layout_columnWeight="1"
```

Comment: I it now available one pre API 21 with the support library latest release. Just add the dependency - com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:22.0.0

Comment: @oznus I tried with with this, still no use. Its not taking weight property.

Comment: When using the new `GridLayout` you should use the `app` namespace, so it would be `app:layout_gravity="fill"`

Comment: In my experience for the weights to work properly you have to set `layot_width` to `0dp` @NigamPatro hope this helps

Comment: Just a heads up because this took me forever to figure out. If you are developping for API 28 or higher there is a new support library called AndroidX available. If `android.useAndroidX` is set to true in your gradle.properties file, the old support libraries **will not work**. For some reason this was the case for me. But all you have to do to fix that is use `androidx.gridlayout.widget.GridLayout` instead of `android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout` and youre good to go.

Comment: This is great. Also, remember to use `android:layout_rowWeight="1"` if you have multiple rows that you want to be the same

Answer (score 16):

For pre API 21, use support library:

add

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

to your dependencies.

Then in your xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:columnCount="2"
                    app:orientation="horizontal"
                    app:rowCount="1">

                    <TextView
                        android:text="1"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:text="2"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        app:layout_columnWeight="1" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Here note the use of "app" prefix and dont forget to add

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

to your xml file

Answer (score 11):

adding views dynamically in a grid Layout of 2 columns that take 50% of the available space:

```
GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout();

View view; //it can be any view

GridLayout.LayoutParams param = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();

param.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(GridLayout.UNDEFINED,GridLayout.FILL,1f);

param.width = 0;

view.setLayoutParams(param);

gridLayout.add(view);
```

in static way (in .xml file).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   app:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
   app:columnCount="2"
   app:columnOrderPreserved="false"
   app:orientation="horizontal"
   android:layout_margin="20dp"
   android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
   android:padding="4dp"
   app:rowCount="2">

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_username"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="@string/user_name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_first_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_row="0"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:text="@string/first_name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_middle_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_column="0"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_row="1"
    android:text="@string/middle_name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/edit_profile_last_name" 
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_column="1"
    app:layout_gravity="fill"
    app:layout_columnWeight="1"
    app:layout_row="1"
    android:text="@string/last_name" />

</android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Comment: Works like a charm! There is also a layout_rowWeight to be combined with layout_height="0dp".

Comment: Programmatical part works for me.

Comment: with the programmatical solution, how can i make it stay within the confine of an specific height? keep taking the whole screen

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so I gave up on the grid view and just used a some linear layouts. I made a vertical one and then added 2 horizontals. It's slightly more involved than the grid view... but until I figure that out at least this works.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_mybutton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/pomegranate"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionmybutton"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_prefs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@color/pomegranate"
            android:contentDescription="@string/contentDescriptionSettings"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_settings" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then i add this to make the buttons square :)

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);

  btnPrefs.setMinimumHeight(btnPrefs.getWidth());
  btnVerse.setMinimumHeight(btnMyButton.getWidth());

 }
```

Comment: I wanted to make my buttons as high as long and I used the code you provided. It works, but I wonder why it doesn't have effect in `onCreate` in an `Activity`. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the RelativeLayout class (or use LinearLayout if you want to) to make sure the height of the item will be the same as the height.

```
public class GridItem extends RelativeLayout {

        public GridItem(Context context) {
                super(context);
        }

        public GridItem(Context context, AttributeSet attr) {
                super(context, attr);
        }

        public GridItem(Context context, AttributeSet attr, int integer) {
                super(context, attr, integer);
        }

        // Override onMeasure to give the view the same height as the specified width
        @Override
        public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
        }

}
```

The parent view of the item layout should be the GridItem view to make sure it works. This must be the layout file you'll inflate in the getView of your ListAdapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<my.packagename.GridItem xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- The content of the item -->

</my.packagename.GridItem>
```

And set the stretchMode of the GridView to columnWidth. This will make all items fit to the width specified number of columns. The new view will make sure they will also have the same height.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridList"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `GridLayoutManager` you are able to use `setSpanSizeLookup`. Here is a snippet from my project which should help to use this method properly:

```
if (mAdapter == null) {
    final int columnCount = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.numberGridColumns);
    mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), columnCount);
    mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
        @Override
        public int getSpanSize(int position) {
            switch (mAdapter.getItemViewType(position)) {
                case ListAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_ONE_COLUMN:
                    return columnCount;
                case RecipeListAdapter.VIEW_TYPE_FULL_COLUMN:
                default:
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    });
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    mAdapter = new RecipeListAdapter(mPresenter);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```